# Android - move data from getApplicationDocumentsDirectory folder to another device?

Tags: android

Does anybody know of an app that will export/import data from an app's "application document directory"?

Comment: What kind of data? And import in what?

Comment: There are lots of different apps available for moving data from one device to another, However, I can’t find an app that will port the data created by an app that is stored in the application documents directory

Comment: What is full path of that application documents directory (where i never heard from..).

Comment: I thinks it’s “app/data/(package name)”

Comment: That path does not exist on an Android device.